# Xcode does not quit after test

Tags: xcode8, xcode-server

I am using `Server` and `Xcode 8`. I saw a new feature, to isolate the testing, for each integration bot a new Xcode is launched. But it can not quit itself after the integration is completed :) and then Xcode crashes and no integration tests can be runned.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to terminate Xcode after the integration completes, you might be able to accomplish this by adding a "Post-Integration Script" on the "Triggers" tab of the the Bot configuration screen.

[image: Xcode Bot Integration Triggers]

A bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill $(ps aux | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}')
```

would be executed on the completion of integration and kill and active Xcode process.